# books into movies - data set suggestions

Tags: machine-learning, web-scraping, dataset, data-science

currently I'm working on a project that predicts book likelihood to be a best-seller movie.
for that, we need some massive data-set of books that already been transformed into movies.
I thought maybe to scrape GoodReads, and maybe IMDb and Wikipedia.
any idea if such data-set already exists out there? if not, do you think I scrape the right sites? any recommendations for other sites maybe? and lastly, what is a good amount of data required for this purpose?